# How to get rid of NA's without erasing the values named "NA"

Tags: r, na

I am working on a dataset where a column is the ISO Country Code (for instance US, GB, DE etc etc). One of these codes is NA, which is Namibia.

When writing my CSV

`write.csv2(df_FINAL, "Final_Merge.csv", col.names =TRUE, row.names = FALSE, na ="")`

the cells for Namibia in the column "Country Code" will be printed as blank.

Is there a way to have `na=""` and excluding a column from the process, so that I can avoid the erasing of the Namibia's values?

I can not change the country code because it has to remain consistent over many dataframes.

Added comment: I reviewed the script and it seems like the problem is how R reads the values when importing the dataframe. Basically, R reads the Namibia cells as Not Available ones. After that, no matter what, they will remain as Not Available. Solution: when using `read.csv2` add `na.strings=""` as suggested in the anwswer.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as an answer, so I'll post as a comment: have you considered other file formats? RDS and feather, I think, would both be excellent.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this behaviour, with such code:

    DF <- data.frame(x=c("NA", "NO"), y=c(1,2))
    write.csv2(DF, "scratch.csv", na="")

The csv file I open with a text editor has "NA" where it should be. Maybe the problem is in reading the final file?

Comment: I reviewed the script and it seems like the problem is how R reads the values when importing the dataframe. Basically, R reads the Namibia cells as Not Available ones. After that, no matter what, they will remain as Not Available. Maybe I could fill the cells for Namibia after the file-import with a ´ifelse´ function

Comment: there's an argument na.strings in read.csv/read.csv2, if you're using those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is with reading actual strings "NA" as NA values, read.csv2 function has an argument `na.strings`, which has a default value of `"NA"`. That should be changed to something different, maybe even `""`. I've also seen `"<NA>"` used in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could first replace `NA` values with empty string in your R script, before you write.  Then, call `write.csv` as you were:

```
df_FINAL <- data.frame(iso <- c("US", "GB", "DE", "NA", NA), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df_FINAL$iso[is.na(df_FINAL$iso)] <- ""
write.csv2(df_FINAL, "Final_Merge.csv", col.names =TRUE, row.names = FALSE, na ="")
```

If you are also having issues *reading* your source file which contains `NA` for the Namibia ISO country code, then set `na.strings` to something other than its default `NA` value:

```
df_FINAL <- read.csv(file="path/to/your/input.csv", na.strings="")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately it seems like the problem is that R reads the Namibia's values as Not available ones when importing the file.

Comment: @Peter So the plot thickens.  Use `na.strings=""` when initially calling `read.csv` or `read.table`.